# Binary search program doesn't work as expected.What's wrong?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, binary-search

I am getting value as "None" in my program?Where have I gone wrong?

```
lis2 = [1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 8, 12]
lis2 = sorted(lis2)
start = 0
end = len(lis2)
mid = (start+end)/2

def binary_search(i):
    global mid,start,end
    if i==lis2[mid]:
        return "Found"
    elif i<lis2[mid]:
        end = mid-1
        mid = (start+end)/2
    elif i>lis2[mid]:
        start = mid+1
        mid = (start+end)/2
    else:
        return "Not Found"

    binary_search(i)


print(binary_search(6))
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make the final line of your function `return binary_search(i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three mistakes are present -

- First as mentioned in the comment and one of the answer you wrote - `binary_search(i)` instead of `return binary_search(i)`
- Second is logical error. Your code will run into infinite loop if the elements is not present in the list. To avoid this check if `start > end`, if ti happens then element is not present.
- Third you initialised `end` to `len(lis2)` , this will give `IndexError: list index out of range` if you are trying to search for an element which is not present in the list and is greater than the max element in the list ( say 23 ). So change `end = len(lis2)` to `end = len(lis2)-1`

Correct Code -

```
lis2 = [1, 3, 6, 2, 5, 4, 8, 12]
lis2 = sorted(lis2)
start = 0
end = len(lis2)-1
mid = int((start+end)/2)

def binary_search(i):
     global mid,start,end
     if(start>end):
        return "Not Found"
     if i==lis2[mid]:
        return "Found"
     elif i<lis2[mid]:
        end = mid-1
        mid = int((start+end)/2)
     elif i>lis2[mid]:
         start = mid+1
         mid = int((start+end)/2)
     return binary_search(i)

print(binary_search(6))
```

Comment: Works perfect!Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

at the end of your function, you need to return the result when calling the function recursivley :

```
def binary_search(i):
global mid,start,end
if i==lis2[mid]:
    return "Found"
elif i<lis2[mid]:
    end = mid-1
    mid = (start+end)/2
elif i>lis2[mid]:
    start = mid+1
    mid = (start+end)/2
else:
    return "Not Found"

return binary_search(i) # <----- EDITED
```